# Update some record with value from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: materials and colors;

I insert color, and then I want to add its id to material record;

So I do:

```
INSERT INTO colors (color) VALUES ('red');
```

After that I want to update materials with specified materials.id(for ex. 3);

So I need something like:

```
UPDATE materials 
SET material='glass',price=100,color_id=(colors.id WHERE color='red')
WHERE id=3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed the select statement.

```
UPDATE materials 
SET material='glass',price=100, color_id=(select colors.id WHERE 
color='red')
WHERE id=3;
```

Comment: To be on the safe side, add `MAX(colors.id)` to work around duplicate rows which would make the `INSERT` fail.

Comment: that's right, unless the color column is unique, as his query let to guess. But better safe than sorry :)

Comment: @Stavr00 In SQLite, such a subquery [never fails](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq).

Comment: Color column is unique. It works but with some edit: `color_id=(SELECT id FROM colors WHERE color="red")`;